# how to save and post JS code result in Webgl within ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webgl

Currently I have two input text area for users to write the Javascript and JS Library on the browser and run it with a run button. Here is the view html:

```
<textarea id="scriptJS" rows="20" style="width:100%;">
</textarea> 
<textarea id="libsJS" rows="20" style="width:100%;">
</textarea>

<button id="btn-run">Run</button>

<canvas id='your_canvas'></canvas> </br>
```

By clicking Run, the Canvas will render the image as the result of the code (Webgl). Below is the Javascript I have in order to make this possible:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#btn-run").on('click', function(){
    scriptJS = $("#scriptJS").val();
    libsJS = $("#libsJS").val();
    eval(libsJS);
    eval(scriptJS);
    main();
  });
});
```

Now what I need to know in Ruby on Rails is how do I write this so that when the user click run, the result image in the Canvas (webgl) is saved and automatically rendered on the users profile. I need the 3d webgl image result be saved and posted with the code so that you can still interact with the image in the canvas after it is saved and posted. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Cant see any ruby code there but i guess you want to transfer the rendered image to the server, doing so requires you to create the webgl context with 'preserveDrawingbuffer'. When enabled you can call toDataURL on the canvas element and get a jpg/png whatever base64 string you can send to your server using ajax.

Oh and take some of this while you're at it: [eval is evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)